# Definition of Diamond Operator

Tags: modular-forms, hecke-algebras

I'm studying modular forms, but I can't understand the definition of diamond operator.

[image]

Why can I define for all $\alpha$ with $\delta \equiv d$? I can't understand the reason why two different matrix $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ with $\delta \equiv \delta'\equiv d$ give the same operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha, \alpha'$ are two matrices in $\Gamma_0(N)$ with bottom right entry congruent to $d \pmod N$, then they are equal up to left multiplication by an element of $\Gamma_1(N)$. Indeed, this is just saying that the map which sends $\alpha$ to its bottom right entry, is a group homomorphism
$$\Gamma_0(N) \to (\mathbb Z / N \mathbb Z)^\times$$
with kernel $\Gamma_1(N)$. So if $\alpha = \gamma \alpha'$ with $\gamma \in \Gamma_1(N)$, then
$$f[\alpha']_k = f[\gamma \alpha]_k = (f[\gamma]_k)[\alpha]_k = f[\alpha]_k$$
because $f \in \mathcal M_k(\Gamma_1(N))$.

Comment: You beat me on that by one minute :) . Besides, diamond operators are much more easily understood once the modular interpretation of the modular curves are given.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I understood.

Comment: @AndreaMori Could you maybe explain the action of the diamond operators once the modular interpretation of the modular curves is given?

Comment: @Nom: The quotients $Y_0(N)={\cal H}/\Gamma_0(N)$ and $Y_1(N)={\cal H}/\Gamma_1(N)$ parametrize pairs $(E,C)$ and $(E,P)$ resp. where $C$ is a cyclic subgroup of $E$ of order $N$ and $P\in E$ ia a point of exact order $N$. Thus modular forms of weight $k$ for $\Gamma_1(N)$ can be seen as functions on triples $(E,P,\omega)$ which is homogeneous of degree $k$ in the variable $\omega$, an invariant differential $1$-form on $E$. With this description the diamond operator $\langle d\rangle$ associated to $d\in({\Bbb Z}/N{\Bbb Z})^\times$ is simply $\langle d\rangle f(E,P,\omega)=f(E,dP,\omega)$.

Comment: @AndreaMori Thank you! Is it maybe known how $\langle d \rangle$ acts on cusps of $X_1(N)=\mathcal{H}^* / \Gamma_1(N) ?$